# jquery viewport info not passed to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, viewport

I'm trying and failing to send the viewport width and heigth to a PHP file!

I know this or rather many similar questions about passing to PHP have already been asked and I've been going through these as well. However, I haven't figured out why it doesn't work for me...

I get the following output, where the second line would match the first, if the data had been passed:

```
Your viewport width is 1519x766
Width is: 880 and Height is 495
```

I just can't get the information passed to the PHP part - tried it like this in one file and also in two files, where I then call the php file using:

```
<?php include 'panzoom.php';?>
```

I use this code in the head:

```
<script>
var viewportwidth;
var viewportheight;

viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
viewportheight = window.innerHeight

document.write('<p>Your viewport width is '+viewportwidth+'x'+viewportheight+'</p>');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                width        : viewportwidth,
                height       : viewportheight
            }
          });   
    });
</script>

<?php 
    $GLOBALS['directory'] = "photos/frontpage/"; 

    if(isset($_POST['width']) && isset($_POST['height'])) {
        $GLOBALS['width'] = $_POST['width'];
        $GLOBALS['height'] = $_POST['height'];
    }else{
        $GLOBALS['width'] = 880;
        $GLOBALS['height'] = 495;   
    }

$width = $GLOBALS['width'];
$height = $GLOBALS['height'];

echo        '<p>Width is: ' . $width . ' and Height is ' . $height . '</p>';            
?>
```

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump( $_POST );` ?

Comment: Just a point: Dont use `url: 'http://localhost/index.php'` just use `url: 'index.php'` as when you move this to a live hosting package the site will not be called `localhost` and this will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You have posted a JSON string to the PHP script and it is called `data` so you should be looking for `$_POST['data']`

Also as it is posted as a json string, in order to make sense of it in PHP you normally decode it to either an array or a string using `json_decode()`

You also dont need to create all the variables in javascript to clutter up the global namespace.

So try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<p>Your viewport width is '+
               window.innerWidth+'x'+window.innerHeight+'</p>');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                width        : window.innerWidth,
                height       : window.innerHeight
            }
          });   
    });
</script>

<?php 
    $GLOBALS['directory'] = "photos/frontpage/"; 

    if( isset($_POST['data']) ) {
        $obj = json_decode($_POST['data']);

        $GLOBALS['width'] = $obj->width;
        $GLOBALS['height'] = $obj->height;
    }else{
        $GLOBALS['width'] = 880;
        $GLOBALS['height'] = 495;   
    }

$width = $GLOBALS['width'];
$height = $GLOBALS['height'];

echo '<p>Width is: ' . $width . ' and Height is ' . $height . '</p>';            
?>
```

Comment: Hey Jimmy, got any comment? Did it work? Did something not work?

Comment: Sorry - lost internet here in the jungle for the past 5 days along with water and while I smell funny and have never been this dirty, I still missed the internet a whole lot more!

I'm checking if the above solutions work and either way, thanks for helping out :)

Comment: RiggsFolly - I just tried putting in your suggestion as above, while commenting out my own stuff. 
However, it still prints the same ->
Width is: 880 and Height is 495

When you use the above code snippet, do you get the width and height passed properly and displayed by the PHP snippet, cause I don't?
I'll take a closer look and see if I'm doing something (more) wrong...

Comment: unixarmy - when I run var_dump( $_POST ); in my PHP snippet after setting the globals as above, I get an empty:
 array(0) { }
So something is off . . .  
The Ajax thing isn't sending the values properly or they aren't received properly or ?